# How to programmatically make tabular rows using `\whiledo` ?

Tags: conditionals, loops

**The following code snippet does not work:**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{xyz}
\setcounter{xyz}{0}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*2{c|}}
\hline
\whiledo{\value{xyz}<10}%
{%
\thexyz & something\stepcounter{xyz} \\\hline%
}%
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\newcounter{xyz}\newcounter{uvw}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\resettabtoks
\loop\ifnum\theuvw<10\relax
  \stepcounter{uvw}
  \addtabtoks{\thexyz & something\stepcounter{xyz} \\\hline}%
\repeat
\begin{longtable}{|*2{c|}}\hline
\printtabtoks
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. This solution is also informative that lets me know the plain tex.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ifthen, xspace}
\newcounter{xyz}
\setcounter{xyz}{0}

\begin{document}
\def\and{&\xspace}
\begin{longtable}{|*2{c|}}
\hline
\whiledo{\value{xyz}<10}%
{%
\thexyz \and something\stepcounter{xyz} \\\hline%
}%
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

**Edit** Changed from minimal class to article (see comments).

Comment: I don't think that's the right way to do things. I'm not sure exactly what's going on here, but the rules don't appear so something fishy is going on.

Comment: thanks for answering. I got a result without horizontal and vertical tabular rules after compiling your code.

Comment: @xport: changing the class to `article` solves the problem (although I don't know why).

Comment: @Bruno It puzzled me ever since!

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Have you found the reason of this puzzle?

Comment: @Forgiver Yes, it was due to the OP having used the minimal class. There was a follow up question by Bruno, will find it out a bit later and post the link.