# problem with using loop inside the tabular environment

Tags: tables, loops

I am having trouble with using a loop inside a tabular environment:

```
\newcounter{it}
\setcounter{it}{0}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \loop\ifnum\theit<4
    \addtocounter{it}{1}
    Q & A\\
  \repeat
\end{tabular}
```

I receive an error about argument of loop having an extra } and the compilation stops at &. I don't get an error when it is a single column table, but even in that case the result is not as expected: I get a single execution of the loop in place of 4.

Can someone tell me what I am missing? Is there special considerations when using loops inside tabular?

Comment: I found out that to solve the problem with & I can define something like \def\tand{&} and use \tand in place of &. But I still get an incorrect output.

Comment: Some crosslinks in case someone come across this question: [Question using `\foreach`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309765/250119). See also [expansion - Completely expandable loop macro that also works in tabular - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196856/completely-expandable-loop-macro-that-also-works-in-tabular?rq=1) and [tables - Extra line in a tabular using expl3 syntax - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70470/extra-line-in-a-tabular-using-expl3-syntax?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, don't do that. tabulars are really special and macro-unfriendly (for instance every `&` closes a group).

Try

```
\def\mylines{}%
\loop\ifnum\theit<4
  \addtocounter{it}{1}
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\mylines\expandafter{%
    \mylines
    Q & A\\
  }%
\repeat
```

*outside* the tabular and then

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \mylines
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 12):

collect all lines with a token register and then print the lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{it}  \setcounter{it}{0}
\newtoks\tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\tabtoks\expandafter{\the\tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\tabtoks}
\begin{document}

\resettabtoks
\loop\ifnum\theit<4
  \stepcounter{it} \addtabtoks{Q & A\\}
\repeat

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\printtabtoks
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This technique has been introduced [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7594/9467) by you as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your own answer has to deal with the extra line problem. Here is a way to do that without having to separately construct the last line thereby keeping your table line structure in one place inside the loop. I threw in a `\hline` or two to show they don't upset the applecart either.

[image: Solution Output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\tand{&}

\begin{document}
%
\newcounter{it}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
  \setcounter{it}{1}%
  \whiledo{\theit<4}{%
    Q \tand A \\%
    \ifnum\value{it}=3\hline\end{tabular}\fi
  \stepcounter{it}%
  }%
 \par Immediately after the table
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The latex kernel has some loops, but with the `@` letter, thus their use is not so widespread. The `\whiledo` of `ifthen` is a wrapper of the `\@whilesw` of the latex kernel; the latter is expandable, whereas the `\whiledo` wrapper of `ifthen` is not. However, here as shown in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50303/4686) of the OP's as well as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142490/4686), one can use with success `\whiledo`.

It is possible to recycle the `\@whilesw` of `LaTeX` and then, there is no problem with the final line in the tabular.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% \usepackage{ifthen} % not needed

% \def\tand{&} % not needed

% recycling the \@whilesw of LaTeX into a num test
% pay attention to correctly end explicit numbers in 
% \ifnum tests with a space, if they are last.
\makeatletter
  \def\xwhilenum #1\do{\@whilesw{\ifnum #1}\fi }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcounter{it}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
  \setcounter{it}{1}%
  \xwhilenum{4>\value{it}}\do {%
    \stepcounter{it}%
     Q & A \\
  }%
\hline
\end{tabular}
\makeatother
 \par Immediately after the tabular
%

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
  before & the loop \\
  \setcounter{it}{1}%
  \xwhilenum{4>\value{it}}\do {%
    \stepcounter{it}%
     Q & A \\
  }%
  still in & the tabular \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\makeatother
 \par Immediately after the tabular
%
\end{document}
```

> [image: while loop in tabular]

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by using a while loop instead:

```
\def\tand{&}

\newcounter{it}
\begin{tabular}{ll}%
  \setcounter{it}{1}%
  \whiledo{\theit<3}{%
    Q \tand A \\%
  \stepcounter{it}%
  }%
  {\theit} \tand \\
\end{tabular}
```

PS: if wondering why I need to print the last one separately, the reason is that the execution leave a partial line (I am using `tabular{|l|l|}`).

Answer (score 1):

I solved a same problem using different approach. For me this solution is more beginner-friendly, very comprehensive while simpler. 
**BUT** here you no more need to loop inside a *macro-unfriendly* environment like **tabular{}** but loop outside to make a temporary file that will be **\input**ted inside it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=Rows.txt

\newcount\foo
\foo=1
\loop
  \immediate\write\tempfile{\the\foo & Q &  \unexpanded{\bf}{A 
\the\foo} \unexpanded{\\}}
\advance \foo +1
\ifnum \foo<5
\repeat

\immediate\closeout\tempfile

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\csname @@input\endcsname Rows.txt
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]