# Display wide and long table

Tags: tables

In the appendix of my report, I would like to add a table. The problem is that I have a cell "description" that contains too much text to be displayed on one line, now the row "overflows" on the right. Also there is too many row to be contained on one single page. Is it possible to display my data such as

- Fixed width
- multi-line cell for the description
- Displayed on several pages

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at the `tabu` package. This extends the well known `tabularx` and `longtable` so that you can easily handle them both without writing to a aux file.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

% showcase only strip that
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50296/problem-with-using-loop-inside-the-tabular-environment
\newcounter{my}
\setcounter{my}{0}

\def\myinsert{}%
\loop\ifnum\themy<100
  \addtocounter{my}{1}
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\myinsert\expandafter{%
    \myinsert
    Quite a big cell content  & Not so big content but bigger cell \\
  }%
\repeat
% end showcase 

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to .5\textwidth{X[1]X[2]} % half the width of the text
\myinsert
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Any additional information can also be found in the `tabu` documentation (`texdoc tabu`)

Comment: Thank you, actually it seems longtable alone is already enough for what I need to do. `\begin{longtable}{|c|l|p{8cm}|}`