# Table too large for longtable?

Tags: longtable, sweave

i have a very wide table that will not fit on a page horizontally (nrow = 127, ncol = 60).  I am using longtable to handle the number of rows (breaking onto the next page when the number of rows are too long for one page) but i would like a way to handle breaking the columns so that they will fit on the page and expand to other pages when necessary (like how longtable handles row breaks).  My current plan was to simply break the table into several sub-tables and print each sub-table separately.  But when the amount of data in the table is large, pdflatex fails.  I can print each sub-table individually fine (i.e., have the code just print table 1 or table 5).  I can print up to 3 tables total fine.  but when i try to print all of the tables it fails.  The only way i can print all 5 tables ok is to limit the number of rows of data to 92.   I have not found the log file to be very helpful as there is no error listed.

is this a memory issue?  a miktek 2.9 issue?  I am using RStudio and Sweave to make this document.  The files and data are too large to paste here, but i can try and upload something if someone can tell me how to do that.

---

As requested, here is a set of excerpts from the log file on the failed run:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.2.22)  23 FEB 2015 13:52
entering extended mode
**C:/Users/ericad/Documents/R*working/HH_DS/trial.tex
("C:/Users/ericad/Documents/R working/HH_DS/trial.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\report.cls"
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count88
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"
Package: color 2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 130.
)
(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\framed\framed.sty
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip43
\fb@frw=\dimen105
\fb@frh=\dimen106
\FrameRule=\dimen107
\FrameSep=\dimen108
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\alltt.sty"
Package: alltt 1997/06/16 v2.0g defines alltt environment
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\mathpazo.sty"
Package: mathpazo 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
\symupright=\mathgroup4
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count89
\Gm@cntv=\count90
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count91
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen110
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen111
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen112
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen113
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen114
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen115
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen116
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrextend.sty
Package: scrextend 2015/01/14 v3.15 KOMA-Script package (extend other classes w
ith features of KOMA-Script classes)
(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2015/01/14 v3.15 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2015/01/14 v3.15 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2015/01/14 v3.15 KOMA-Script package (loading files)

Package scrlfile, 2015/01/14 v3.15 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))))

Package scrextend Warning: Using fallback calculation to setup font sizes
(scrextend)                for basic size `9' on input line 65.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\tabularx.sty"
Package: tabularx 1999/01/07 v2.07 `tabularx' package (DPC)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\array.sty"
Package: array 2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen117
\extrarowheight=\dimen118
\NC@list=\toks16
\extratabsurround=\skip44
\backup@length=\skip45
)
\TX@col@width=\dimen119
\TX@old@table=\dimen120
\TX@old@col=\dimen121
\TX@target=\dimen122
\TX@delta=\dimen123
\TX@cols=\count92
\TX@ftn=\toks17
)
(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\colortbl\colortbl.sty
Package: colortbl 2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
\everycr=\toks18
\minrowclearance=\skip46
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \color on input line 702.
\rownum=\count93
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty
Package: caption 2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)

(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)
Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 57.
\captionmargin=\dimen124
\captionmargin@=\dimen125
\captionwidth=\dimen126
\caption@tempdima=\dimen127
\caption@indent=\dimen128
\caption@parindent=\dimen129
\caption@hangindent=\dimen130
)
\c@ContinuedFloat=\count94
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\longtable.sty"
Package: longtable 2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip47
\LTright=\skip48
\LTpre=\skip49
\LTpost=\skip50
\LTchunksize=\count95
\LTcapwidth=\dimen131
\LT@head=\box26
\LT@firsthead=\box27
\LT@foot=\box28
\LT@lastfoot=\box29
\LT@cols=\count96
\LT@rows=\count97
\c@LT@tables=\count98
\c@LT@chunks=\count99
\LT@p@ftn=\toks19
)
(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty
\fancy@headwidth=\skip51
\f@ncyO@elh=\skip52
\f@ncyO@erh=\skip53
\f@ncyO@olh=\skip54
\f@ncyO@orh=\skip55
\f@ncyO@elf=\skip56
\f@ncyO@erf=\skip57
\f@ncyO@olf=\skip58
\f@ncyO@orf=\skip59
)
(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\setspace\setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
)
(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\hyphenat\hyphenat.sty
Package: hyphenat 2009/09/02 v2.3c hyphenation utilities
\langwohyphens=\language69
LaTeX Info: Redefining \_ on input line 43.
)
(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\upquote\upquote.sty
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
Package: textcomp 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 71.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 266.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 281.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 282.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 283.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 284.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 285.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 286.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 287.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 288.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 289.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 290.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 291.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 292.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 293.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 294.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 295.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 296.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 297.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 298.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 299.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 300.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 301.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 302.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 303.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 304.

Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 305.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 306.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 307.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 308.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 309.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 310.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 311.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 312.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 313.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 314.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 315.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 316.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 317.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 318.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 319.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 320.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 321.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 322.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 323.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 324.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 325.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 326.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 327.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 328.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 329.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 330.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 331.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 332.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 333.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 335.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 336.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 337.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 338.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 339.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 340.
))
No file trial.aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 213.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 213.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+pplx on input line 213.


("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\t1pplx.fd"
File: t1pplx.fd 2004/09/06 font definitions for T1/pplx.
)
(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count100
\scratchdimen=\dimen132
\scratchbox=\box30
\nofMPsegments=\count101
\nofMParguments=\count102
\everyMPshowfont=\toks20
\MPscratchCnt=\count103
\MPscratchDim=\dimen133
\MPnumerator=\count104
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count105
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks21
)
\big@size=\dimen134

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

Package geometry Warning: The marginal notes overrun the paper.
     Add 4.86812pt and more to the right margin.

*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(71.13188pt, 1086.32623pt, 71.13188pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(71.13188pt, 652.70622pt, 71.13188pt)
* \paperwidth=1228.59pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=1086.32623pt
* \textheight=652.70622pt
* \oddsidemargin=-1.1381pt
* \evensidemargin=-1.1381pt
* \topmargin=-38.1381pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=8.09998pt plus 3.5996pt minus 1.80037pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: longtable package is loaded.
(C:\Users\ericad\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\caption\ltcaption.sty
Package: ltcaption 2013/02/03 v1.3-62 longtable captions (AR)
)
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
```

Comment: Can't reproduce with TeX Live 2014 and 5 `longtable`s each with 127 rows and 12 columns (all values of 0.0). I get 15 pages of material, and no errors.

Comment: what does `pdflatex fails` mean? I had test cases of longtables running to several thousand pages using the machines available in the 1990's basically it only holds one page in memory at a time. So it is rather surprising that you run out of memory, unless the individual cells are large, a 10000 node tikz picture in every cell may start to eat into tex's main mem,

Comment: Please post the log file of a "failed" run.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: well then can someone please tell me how to load the log file properly then.  simply telling me to not do something isn't very helpful.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of copying the contents of the log file, which posted as an "answer", into the body of your posting. Judging by the log file, you load an awful lot of packages. Are all these packages needed?

Comment: i've commented out most of them as i don't think that they are needed.  right now i know that i need scrextend, mathpazo, fontenc, graphicx, xcolor, caption, longtable and fancyhdr.  but i still have the same problems.

Comment: I've had problems with sweave documents on Windows. Are you inserting images in your table?

Comment: no, no images.  I reworked the file so that i wasn't using any unnecessary packages.  according to the log file it just stops after "Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code."

Comment: How exactly are you splitting the table into 5? Do you have 5 `longtable` environments?

Comment: are you still running your example via sweave or can you make a pure tex example? The log can not just stop like that unless an external process killed TeX so getting an example divorced from the R/TeX sweave processing pipeline would help debugging. But I'm confused as the log file in your deleted answer shows pdflatex completing without error and making a 6 page pdf. `Output written on Report_2015_2_6.pdf (6 pages, 232718 bytes)`

Answer (score 1):

Yet another fake answer, just an attempt to narrow down a proper MWE. I can't reproduce the problem with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50299
\newcounter{it}
\setcounter{it}{0}
\def\mylines{}%
\loop\ifnum\theit<127
  \addtocounter{it}{1}
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\mylines\expandafter{%
\mylines
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
  }%
\repeat

\begin{longtable}{cccccccccccc}
\caption{First} \\
\mylines
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{cccccccccccc}
\caption{Second} \\
\mylines
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{cccccccccccc}
\caption{Third} \\
\mylines
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{cccccccccccc}
\caption{Fourth} \\
\mylines
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{cccccccccccc}
\caption{Fifth} \\
\mylines
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

either using the compact `\mylines` macro as shown, or by hard-coding 127 lines in each table. 15 pages either way, no errors. TeX Live 2014 on Windows. If this document works for you, Erica, then you'll have to start identifying the differences between your failing document and this one to narrow down the cause of your error.

Comment: thanks.  i know it's hard to reproduce the error i was having.  i found the error actually, in a script that i wrote to help produce the LaTeX table.  i appreciate your help!