# Alternating \rowcolor using \if

Tags: tables, rowcolor

I know that the best way to altern row color is using `\rowcolors{2}{}{}` but on my .tex file `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` doesn't work so I am trying to reach the same result with `\if`.

I would like to insert in `\foreach` this:

`\if` `\i` is odd then `\rowcolor{grey!10}` else nothing.

My code is the following.

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \toprule
        {} & {\bf Carbon} & {\bf Hydrogen} & {\bf Nitrogen} & {\bf Oxygen\tnote{a}} & {\bf pH}\\
        \midrule
        \foreach \M[count=\i] in {a,b,c,d}{
            {\bf \M} & - & - & - & - & -\\
        }
        \bottomrule
    \end {tabular}
\end {table}
```

The result should be the following.

[image]

Comment: "doesn't work "  what error do you get? Please always make your example scomplete documents so people can test answers. Your fragment uses several commands that are not defined by default in latex, so everyone has to guess which packages you are using.

Comment: Please add a fully compilable MWE next time.

Comment: Please, note that `\bf` (like all similar two letter font commands) has been obsolete for 20 years. Use `\bfseries` or `\textbf` as described in any LaTeX guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, the problem you walked in are for-loops inside tables. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50296/problem-with-using-loop-inside-the-tabular-environment) for example.

For my approach I used the `forloop`-package for iterating the numbers/letters, and `etoolbox` to robustify the linebreak-command. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%for robustify


\def\tabledata{}
\def\lbr{\\}
\robustify\lbr%neverever expand

\newcounter{mynextrowc}
\newcommand\dummyrows[1]{%
    \forloop{mynextrowc}{1}{\value{mynextrowc} < #1}{%
        \edef\tabledata{\tabledata\alph{mynextrowc} & - & - & - & - & -\lbr}
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\dummyrows{15}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \rowcolor{gray!50}
        \toprule
        {} & {\bf Carbon} & {\bf Hydrogen} & {\bf Nitrogen} & {\bf Oxygen {a}} & {\bf pH}\\
        \midrule
        \tabledata
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]