# Problems rebuilding a complex table with subtables

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have problems rebuilding a complex table for my training plan.
A filled macrocycle from the book [Training for Climbing](https://trainingforclimbing.com/buy-books/training-for-climbing-3rd-edition-2016/) looks like:
[image: Macrocycle]

I tried to use tabularx and subtables for the fine grid lines, but it crashs.
Here is a code example (without the subtables):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,landscape]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,pgffor}

\newcommand{\numarr}[1]{%
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{\footnotesize\ \n}
}
\newcommand{\emarr}[1]{%
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{\footnotesize\ \phantom{x}}
}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{.4\textwidth}{@{}r|Y|Y|Y@{}}
    Year & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Header} \\
    \hline
    \phantom{x2022x}%
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{}%
    \\[1cm]
    \hline
    month & Jan & Feb & Mär 
    \\
    \hline
    weak%
    &\numarr{5}%
    &\numarr{4}%
    &\numarr{4}%
    \\
    \hline
    Fokus
    &grid&grid&grid
    \\[3em]
    \hline
    &grid&grid&grid
    \\[3em]
    \hline
    &&&
    \\[8em]
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I would be really happy if someone has a hint or a similar example.

Thank in advance!
Tommy

Comment: The usual approach is to start with the smallest divisions and use \multicolumn and \multirow for the larger divisions.  In other words, weeks (or whatever that is) not months.

Comment: I suspected this answer. Is there an easy and clear way to generate a given number of "&" symbols (perhaps as macro or something else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try the `bytefield` package which is sometimes easier when you would need lots of `\multicolumns` in a table. Since all the gridlines are all the same size though, I added some extra spacing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1em]{67}
\bitbox{15}{\raggedright\ Name/Year}& \bitbox{52}{Training Objectives and Seasonal Climbing Goals}\\
\bytefieldsetup{bitheight=12ex}%
\bitbox{15}{}&\bitboxes{13}{{}{}{}{}}\\
\bytefieldsetup{bitheight=3ex}%

\bitbox{15}{\raggedright\ Month} & \bitbox{5}{Jan} & \bitboxes{4}{{Feb}{Mar}} & \bitbox{5}{Apr} & \bitboxes{4}{{Jun}{May}} & \bitbox{5}{Jul} & \bitboxes{4}{{Aug}{Sep}} & \bitbox{5}{Oct} & \bitboxes{4}{{Nov}{Dec}}\\

\bitbox{15}{\raggedright\ Week} & \bitboxes{1}{{\tiny1} {\tiny2} {\tiny3} {\tiny4} {\tiny5} {\tiny6} {\tiny7} {\tiny8} {\tiny9} {\tiny10} {\tiny11} {\tiny12} {\tiny13} {\tiny14} {\tiny15} {\tiny16} {\tiny17} {\tiny18} {\tiny19} {\tiny20} {\tiny21} {\tiny22} {\tiny23} {\tiny24} {\tiny25} {\tiny26} {\tiny27} {\tiny28} {\tiny29} {\tiny30} {\tiny31} {\tiny32} {\tiny33} {\tiny34} {\tiny35} {\tiny36} {\tiny37} {\tiny38} {\tiny39} {\tiny40} {\tiny41} {\tiny42} {\tiny43} {\tiny44} {\tiny45} {\tiny46} {\tiny47} {\tiny48} {\tiny49} {\tiny50} {\tiny51} {\tiny52}}\\[1ex]

\bitbox[lt]{2}{}&\bitbox{13}{\raggedright\ Stamina/skill}&\bitboxes{1}{{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}\\
\bitbox[l]{2}{}&\bitbox{13}{\raggedright\ Max. Strength and power}&\bitboxes{1}{{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}\\
\bitbox[l]{2}{\rotatebox[origin=tl]{90}{\ \ \ Training focus}}&\bitbox{13}{\raggedright\ Anaerobic Performance}&\bitboxes{1}{{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}\\
\bitbox[lb]{2}{}&\bitbox{13}{\raggedright\ Rest}&\bitboxes{1}{{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}\\[1ex]

\bitbox[lt]{14}{} & \bitbox[tr]{1}{\tiny7} & \bitboxes{1}{{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}\\
\bitbox[l]{14}{} & \bitbox[]{1}{\tiny6} & \bitboxes{1}{{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}\\
\bitbox[l]{14}{} & \bitbox[r]{1}{\tiny5} & \bitboxes{1}{{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}\\
\bitbox[l]{14}{\raggedright\ Total number of days per\\\ week of finger training or\\\ climbing} & \bitbox[]{1}{\tiny4} & \bitboxes{1}{{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}\\
\bitbox[l]{14}{} & \bitbox[]{1}{\tiny3} & \bitboxes{1}{{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}\\
\bitbox[l]{14}{} & \bitbox[]{1}{\tiny2} & \bitboxes{1}{{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}\\
\bitbox[lb]{14}{} & \bitbox[b]{1}{\tiny1} & \bitboxes{1}{{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}\\
\bytefieldsetup{bitheight=18ex}%
\bitbox{15}{\raggedright\ Benchmark achievements\\\ and notes} & \bitbox{5}{} & \bitboxes{4}{{}{}} & \bitbox{5}{} & \bitboxes{4}{{}{}} & \bitbox{5}{} & \bitboxes{4}{{}{}} & \bitbox{5}{} & \bitboxes{4}{{}{}}\\
\end{bytefield}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for implementing the full example ... I already build an own table, but this is more beautiful :-)

Answer (score 0):

After getting the *usual approach* from John Kormylo, I switched to the tabu-package and used the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489775/238225 to generate a numbered (and empty) loop over the calendar weeks.
Here is my way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % English language hyphenation
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\mcfront}[1]{\multicolumn{3}{c!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mcquart}{\multicolumn{13}{c!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{}}
\newcommand{\mcmonth}[1]{\multicolumn{4}{c|}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mcrmonth}[1]{\multicolumn{4}{c!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mclmonth}[1]{\multicolumn{5}{c|}{#1}}

%loop to generate cells
\newcounter{col}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\colloop@add[2]
  {%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\colloop@\expandafter
      {\colloop@@{#1}}%
    \ifnum#2>\value{col}
      \g@addto@macro\colloop@{&}%
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\colloop[2]
  {%
      {%
        \setcounter{col}{0}%
        \gdef\colloop@{}%
        \gdef\colloop@@##1{#2}%
        \loop\ifnum#1>\value{col}
          \stepcounter{col}%
          \expandafter\colloop@add\expandafter{\the\value{col}}{#1}%
        \repeat
      }%
    \colloop@
  }
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \begin{tabu} to .9\textwidth {llr !{\vrule width 1.2pt}Y *{12}{|Y} !{\vrule width 1.2pt}Y *{12}{|Y} !{\vrule width 1.2pt}Y *{12}{|Y} !{\vrule width 1.2pt}Y *{12}{|Y} !{\vrule width 1.2pt}}%
        \tabucline[1.2pt]-
        \rowfont[c]\bfseries
        \multicolumn{3}{c!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{Jahr}& \multicolumn{52}{c!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{Trainings- und Kletterziele} \\
        \tabucline[1.2pt]-
        \mcfront{} & \mcquart & \mcquart & \mcquart & \mcquart
        \\[2cm]
        \tabucline[1.2pt]-
        \multicolumn{3}{r!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{Monat\phantom{x}}
        & \mclmonth{Jan}
        & \mcmonth{Feb}
        & \mcrmonth{Mär}
        & \mclmonth{Apr}
        & \mcmonth{Mai}
        & \mcrmonth{Jun}
        & \mclmonth{Jul}
        & \mcmonth{Aug}
        & \mcrmonth{Sep}
        & \mclmonth{Okt}
        & \mcmonth{Nov}
        & \mcrmonth{Dez}
        \\
        \tabucline[1.4pt]-
        \multicolumn{3}{r!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{Woche\phantom{x}}
        &
        \colloop{52}{\footnotesize #1}
        \\
        \tabucline[1.4pt]-
        \parbox[t]{4mm}{\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Fokus}}}
        & \multicolumn{2}{|c!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{Technik} &\colloop{52}{}\\\tabucline{2-}
        & \multicolumn{2}{|c!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{Max-/Schnellkraft} &\colloop{52}{}\\\tabucline{2-}
        & \multicolumn{2}{|c!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{Kraftausdauer} &\colloop{52}{}\\\tabucline{2-}
        & \multicolumn{2}{|c!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{Anaerobe Ausdauer} &\colloop{52}{}\\\tabucline{2-}
        & \multicolumn{2}{|c!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{Aerobe Ausdauer} &\colloop{52}{}\\\tabucline{2-}
        & \multicolumn{2}{|c!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{Ruhetag} &\colloop{52}{}
        \\
        \tabucline[1.4pt]-
        & \parbox[t]{4mm}{\multirow{8}{*}{\begin{minipage}{8em}\centering Anzahl an Kletter- und Trainingstagen pro Woche\end{minipage}}}
        & \parbox[t]{4mm}{\multirow{8}{*}{\begin{minipage}{1em}\centering\vspace{.3em}7\vspace{.3pt}
        6\vspace{0.3pt}
        5\vspace{0.3pt}
        4\vspace{0.3pt}
        3\vspace{0.3pt}
        2\vspace{0.3pt}
        1\vspace{0.3pt}
        \end{minipage}}}
        &\colloop{52}{}\\\tabucline{4-}
        &&  &\colloop{52}{}\\\tabucline{4-}
        &&  &\colloop{52}{}\\\tabucline{4-}
        &&  &\colloop{52}{}\\\tabucline{4-}
        &&  &\colloop{52}{}\\\tabucline{4-}
        &&  &\colloop{52}{}\\\tabucline{4-}
        &&  &\colloop{52}{}\\\tabucline{4-}
        &&  &\colloop{52}{}
        \\
        \tabucline[1.4pt]-
        \multicolumn{3}{r!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{Gewicht\phantom{x}} &\colloop{52}{}
        \\
        \tabucline[1.4pt]-
        \multicolumn{3}{r!{\vrule width 1.2pt}}{\begin{minipage}{8em}\centering \vspace{2.25cm}Erfolge und Kommentare\vspace{2.25cm}\end{minipage}}
        & \mclmonth{}
        & \mcmonth{}
        & \mcrmonth{}
        & \mclmonth{}
        & \mcmonth{}
        & \mcrmonth{}
        & \mclmonth{}
        & \mcmonth{}
        & \mcrmonth{}
        & \mclmonth{}
        & \mcmonth{}
        & \mcrmonth{}
        \\
        \tabucline[1.4pt]-
    \end{tabu}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

with the result:
[image: Macrocycle from Eric Hörst]

I tried to avoid the tabu-package, but I couldn't rebuild it with `tabularx`.