# How to create horizontal box layout?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I'm trying to create a daily planner for myself that looks somewhat like this.

[image: schedule template]

[image: Tasks template]

My current version

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper, portrait, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\grayline}{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\cline{1-5}\arrayrulecolor{white}}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|X|X|X|X|}
    \cline{1-5}
    \multicolumn{5} {r|} {Date: 2021|\hspace{0.5cm}|\hspace{0.5cm}|}\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
Reflections:
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|l}
 TASKS: \hspace{5cm} & IDEAS: \hspace{5cm} \\ 
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
 \hspace{5cm} & \hspace{5cm} \\
 \cline{1-2}
    
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The end goal is to stack this two a5 pages side by side in one single a4 page.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but you can remove all occurences of `\hspace{0.5cm}` in the first column of your first table if you replace `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|X|X|X|X|}` with `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{wc{0.5cm}|X|X|X|X|}`. In the second table, you can also remove all `\hscpae` commands in both columns if you use `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|X}` instead of `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|l}`. (A `tabularx` environment without any `X` type column does not really make sense and won't adapt to the tetwidth.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're interested in the following `minipage`-based approach:

In the following example, I also removed all `\hspace` commands and instead used fixed or flexible width columns to achieve a similar layout. Intead of repeating the empty lines in the table over and over again, I used loops (inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50299/134144)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\grayline}{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\cline{1-5}\arrayrulecolor{white}}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.475\linewidth}
\newcounter{rownumber}
\setcounter{rownumber}{0}
\def\fillfirsttable{}%
\loop\ifnum\therownumber<12
  \addtocounter{rownumber}{1}
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\fillfirsttable\expandafter{%
    \fillfirsttable
     & & & & \\
    \hline
     & & & & \\
    \grayline
  }%
\repeat
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{wc{0.5cm}|X|X|X|X|}
    \cline{1-5}
    \multicolumn{5} {r|} {Date: 2021|\hspace{0.5cm}|\hspace{0.5cm}|}\\
    \hline
    \fillfirsttable
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.475\linewidth}
Reflections:

\setcounter{rownumber}{0}
\def\fillsecondtable{}%
\loop\ifnum\therownumber<20
  \addtocounter{rownumber}{1}
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\fillsecondtable\expandafter{%
    \fillsecondtable
     & \\ \hline
  }%
\repeat
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|X}
 TASKS: & IDEAS:  \\ \hline
 \fillsecondtable
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```