# Define a Likert scale grid with multiple rows

Tags: questionnaire

I am trying to create a survey and I was hoping to do this with the [eqexam](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/eqexam.html) package, but I can't really figure out how to make a good Likert scale. There are only examples of exams in the documentation and not of surveys.

I am trying to make something like:

```
    Bad NotBad Neutral OK Good
Q1  []    []     []    []  []
Q2  []    []     []    []  []
Q3  []    []     []    []  []
Q4  []    []     []    []  []
```

Should I do this with latex anyway? I am just trying to get a printable survey.

Comment: What is the specific problem? This can be set as a table. For the checkboxes you could use `\square` from the `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: Ah yes, I found that one too. But I was hoping that the eqexam package would actually also include some questionnaire options that I haven't found yet. I have created the tables, but they are a bit messy with positioning, since they are floating objects.

Comment: @Marnix your tabular material need not to be a floating onject; you can use `tabular` *without* `table`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using a `longtable` environment and the method described by **Herbert** in his answer to [How to programmatically make tabular rows using `\whiledo` ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7590/3954) to iteratively build the rows. I defined a `\CheckTable` command with a mandatory argument which builds your table with the number of rows specified in the argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array,longtable}

\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{row}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\newcommand\CheckTable[1]{%
  \setcounter{question}{0}
  \setcounter{row}{0}
  \resettabtoks
  \loop\ifnum\therow<#1\relax
    \stepcounter{row}
    \addtabtoks{& $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\}%
  \repeat
  \begin{longtable}{>{\stepcounter{question}Q\thequestion}l*{5}{c}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Bad & Not Bad & Neutral & OK & Good \\
    \printtabtoks
  \end{longtable}%
}

\begin{document}

\CheckTable{10}

\CheckTable{6}

\CheckTable{12}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like a nice solution. But suppose I would like to have this as an interactive form? I know it is not my goal and question, but I am just curious.

Comment: @Marnix if I understand you correctly, then you could use the [eforms](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eforms) package.