# Longtable overflowing document - how do I define the width of a column?

Tags: tables, longtable, questionnaire, column-width

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57059/define-a-likert-scale-grid-with-multiple-rows?rq=1) question that helped me defining a layout for a Liker questionnaire I have to create. The problem is that with very long questions that very same code is not working. Here is an example of what happens:

[image: Broken Likert]

The code is basically the same as the one shown in the first reply of the previously linked question. The fact is that that code iteratively put Q1-10 as the question while I need to obviously write each question down. So this is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l*{5}{c}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Question} & Bad & Not Bad & Neutral & OK & Good \\
This is a very very very very very very very very very long question & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q2 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q3 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q4 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q5 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q6 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q7 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q8 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q9 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q10 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This is the minimum (non) working example I could create that basically compiles into the resulting image I uploaded.

How can I resize the width of the "Question" block in order not to have the squares for the replies overflow the document?

Thanks!

Comment: You can either use a `p{<width>}` column for the first column or try one of the packages that combine the features of `longtable` with `tabularx` such as `ltablex`, `ltxtable`, `xltabular`,...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible solution uwing the `xltabular` package that combines the features of `longtable`(page breaks within a table)  ad `tabularx` (automatic linebreaks in table cells):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{X*{5}{c}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Question} & Bad & Not Bad & Neutral & OK & Good \\
This is a very very very very very very very very very long question & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q2 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q3 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q4 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q5 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q6 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q7 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q8 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q9 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q10 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Regarding the request in the comments: You can either use `p` type columns and specify the width and the alignment. This will cause an automatic linebreak. If you prefer manual linebreaks in the column headers, you might also want to use `\makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{X>{\Centering}p{2cm}cccc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Question} & a very long column title & Not Bad & Neutral & OK & \makecell[cc]{a second \\ very very long \\ column title} \\
This is a very very very very very very very very very long question & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q2 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q3 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q4 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q5 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q6 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q7 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q8 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q9 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
Q10 & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked wonders! I have one question: can I modify the width of the other columns too? I.e., instead of "Bad" I would like to put something longer and that breaks a bit the layout because the "Question" column gets very narrow. So I would like to fix the width of the other columns too! Thanks!

Comment: @Masiar: I have edited my answer to add two versions on how to control the width of a longer colum headers.