# How to make tabularx columns using \whiledo?

Tags: tables, conditionals, loops, tabularx

My question is similar to that discussed in [How to programmatically make tabular rows using `\whiledo` ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/how-to-programmatically-make-tabular-rows-using-whiledo). The difference is that I want to produce columns rather than rows with using `\whiledo`. Basically I have the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{index}
\setcounter{index}{3}
\newcommand{\Line}{& 1 & 2 & 3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{|r|*{\value{index}}{X|}}
\hline
Some text \Line \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

My task is to redefine the command `\Line` such that it would have one argument, value of the counter `index`. It should produce columns with the content 1, 2, 3, ..., n. Here n is value of the counter `index`.

I am filling that there exists a solution with `\whiledo` but still my attempts to find it are unsuccessful. I would be appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice is to never use `\whiledo` or other loops inside a `tabular` environment or variations thereof.

The strategy is to build the `\Line` macro step by step; producing a `&` in a `tabular` environment would end a cell and break the loop. Better do it when you set the value of `index` for the next job.

```
\newcounter{index}
\newcounter{temp}
\newcommand{\settabindex}[1]{%
  \setcounter{index}{#1}%
  \setcounter{temp}{0}%
  \def\Line{}%
  \whiledo{\value{temp}<\value{index}}
    {\stepcounter{temp}\edef\Line{\Line & \thetemp}}%
}
```

One needs to use `\edef` in order to deliver the previous contents of `\Line` for the next addition of `& \thetemp`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ifthen}

\newcounter{index}
\newcounter{temp}
\newcommand{\settabindex}[1]{%
  \setcounter{index}{#1}%
  \setcounter{temp}{0}%
  \def\Line{}%
  \whiledo{\value{temp}<\value{index}}
    {\stepcounter{temp}\edef\Line{\Line & \thetemp}}%
}

\begin{document}

\settabindex{10}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{|r|*{\value{index}}{X|}}
\hline
Some text \Line \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\settabindex{4}

\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{|r|*{\value{index}}{X|}}
\hline
Some text \Line \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice advice! This works really as I want.