# Gym Workout log template in LaTeX

Tags: templates

Can anyone suggest or, maybe, share their own gym workout logs created using LaTeX? Something like this, for instance.

Template 1: From [Builtlean Source](http://files.builtlean.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Exercise-Log-Template.pdf)

[image]

Template 2: From [Builtlean Source](http://files.builtlean.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Exercise-Log-Template.pdf)

[image]

Comment: +1 for making the effort to give images and care when asking the question (clearly more than I did in my answer :p  )

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof of concept of how to handle the table (inspired by [How to make tabularx columns using \whiledo?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76201/16895))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{index}
\newcounter{temp}
\newcounter{currentline}
\newcounter{numberoflines}

%% This create a command \Line to print a row of n elements, where n is the
%% argument of the command
\newcommand{\settabindex}[1]{%
  \setcounter{index}{#1}%
  \setcounter{temp}{0}%
  \def\Line{}%
  \whileboolexpr{test { \ifnumless{\value{temp}}{\value{index}} }}
    {\stepcounter{temp}\edef\Line{\Line & }}%
}

%% set the counters for how many row we want to print
\newcommand{\setnumberoflines}[1]{
  \setcounter{currentline}{0}
  \setcounter{numberoflines}{#1}
}

%% This is for the second table. We create a command workout that print n
%% workout lines (and increase the counter for each workout)
\newcounter{workout}
\newcommand{\workouts}[1]{%
  \setcounter{workout}{0}%
  \whileboolexpr{test { \ifnumless{\value{workout}}{#1} }}
    {\stepcounter{workout}Workout \theworkout \Line
     \ifnumless{\value{workout}}{#1}{\\\hline}{}}
}  

\begin{document}

%% FIRST TABLE
\settabindex{10}
\setnumberoflines{10}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
  {|X|
  >{\columncolor{cyan!20}}c|
  c|c|
  >{\columncolor{cyan!20}}c|
  c|c|
  >{\columncolor{cyan!20}}c|
  c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{black!15}
  \multicolumn{1}{|l}{Exercise} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{TR} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{AR} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{W} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{TR} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{AR} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{W} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{TR} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{AR} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{W} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{RBS}  
  \whileboolexpr
    {test { \ifnumless{\value{currentline}}{\value{numberoflines}} }}
    {\\\hline\stepcounter{currentline}\Line}\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\newpage

%% SECOND TABLE
\settabindex{8}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|c|c|*{5}{X|}c|}
  \rowcolor{black}
  \textcolor{white}{Exercise} &
  \textcolor{white}{Sets} &
  \textcolor{white}{Reps} &
  \textcolor{white}{Set 1} &
  \textcolor{white}{Set 2} &
  \textcolor{white}{Set 3} &
  \textcolor{white}{Set 4} &
  \textcolor{white}{Set 5} &
  \textcolor{white}{Rest}\\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{}\\
  \hline
  \workouts{4}\\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{}\\
  \hline
  \workouts{5}\\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{}\\
  \hline
  \workouts{3}\\
  \hline
  \workouts{4}\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for just giving links, but I suspect that your best bet will be to find some excel format workout logs ([this page](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/WorkoutLogs.html) has some nice examples but it's the sort of thing where it's probably best to roll your own) and then put them though one of the methods suggested in [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49414/comprehensive-list-of-tools-that-simplify-the-generation-of-latex-tables)...

Comment: Is it possible to illustrate with example how LaTeX Table will help for the others benefit and adding value ?. You can always leave a [comment instead](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111821/gym-workout-log-template-in-latex/111823#comment246443_111821) like above.