# pgfplotstable: how to repeat row entries and combine it with external data

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, multirow

I want to combine the table data (in a file `A.txt`)

```
-0.13336 -0.13634 -0.13336 -0.11589 -0.136 

0.76158 0.63087 0.76158 0.95729 0.63

0.9543 0.59712 0.9543 0.90589 0.59712 

0.17172 0.13013 0.17172 0.18496 0.13013 

4.9543  3.9543 2.9543 5.9543 1.9543
```

which some labels.

The final result should be (like the tex-result of ...)

```
\begin{tabular}{ l|l|lllll }
\multirow{3}{*}{New}  & a & -0.13336 & -0.13634 & -0.13336 & -0.11589 & -0.136 \\
              & z & 0.76158 & 0.63087 & 0.76158 & 0.95729 & 0.63 \\
              & b & 0.9543 & 0.59712 & 0.9543 & 0.90589 & 0.59712 \\
\multirow{3}{*}{Old}  & a & 0.17172 & 0.13013 & 0.17172 & 0.18496 & 0.13013 \\
              & z & 4.9543  & 3.9543 & 2.9543 & 5.9543 & 1.9543 \\
              & b & 0.9543 & 0.59712 & 0.9543 & 0.90589 & 0.59712 \\

\end{tabular}
```

The labels 'a,z,b' are repeated several times and
the  instead of just 'New' and 'Old', I've a lot more Labels (and therefore I've also a longer table...)

I've alread found here at TeX.SX how to combine two tables, but I'm not sure how put it as format option in `\pgfplotstabletypeset`

Comment: Does this answer your question ; http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135084/import-a-table-with-a-specified-format ?