# automatic list/table rendering

Tags: tables, lists, database

i'm looking for a solution to automatically render data lists.
In the current scenario, my input data is a list of strings,
which should be displayed in a three column list w/ sequential numbers:

```
+--------------+-------------+------------+
| 1  xyzxyz    | 2  sadsdasd | 3  sadasdf |
| 4  dfasdfas  | 3  23ea3ad  | 4  898sd   |
|                   .....                 |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

For now, it's enough having a fixed number of items (in my case: 30),
so I've just defined 30 different macros with the values, which are 
then referenced by the template, where everything's just hardcoded.

Of course, that's pretty static, so I'm looking for a better solution,
where the tex input just defines the data like that:

\putItem{xyzxyz}    
\putItem{sadsdasd}  
\putItem{dfasdfas}  
\putItem{23ea3ad}   
\putItem{898sd}     
...

Does anyone have a good idea ?

thx

Comment: Do the strings have spaces in them, or could a space be used as a string separator?

Comment: Also, are these strings in a separate file, or are they being generated by the LaTeX code?

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\putItem[1]{\refstepcounter{enumi}\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{\theenumi. #1}\hfill\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\putItem{xyzxyz}
\putItem{sadsdasd}
\putItem{dfasdfas}
\putItem{23ea3ad}
\putItem{898sd} 
\putItem{xyzxyz}
\putItem{sadsdasd}
\putItem{dfasdfas}
\putItem{23ea3ad}
\putItem{898sd}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a *slight* improvement over David Carlisle's solution in that a simple comma separated list can be spcified:

[image]

### Notes:

- Use a custom counter in case which allows for use within other enumerated environments.
- Counter is rest for each invocation of `\ListTable`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcounter{MyCounter}
\newcommand\putItem[1]{\refstepcounter{MyCounter}\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{\theMyCounter. #1}\hfill\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\DefaultNumberOfColumns}{3}%
\newcommand{\ListTable}[2][\DefaultNumberOfColumns]{%
    % #1 = optional number of columns, defaults to \DefaultNumberOfColumns
    % #2 = common separated list
    \setcounter{MyCounter}{0}%
    \noindent
    \edef\ListMembersExpanded{#2}%
        \foreach \x in \ListMembersExpanded {%
            \IfStrEq{\x}{}{}{% Need to eliminate any empty enteries (allows for trailing comma)
                \putItem{\x}%
            }%
        }%
}%

\ListTable{%
    xyzxyz,
    sadsdasd,
    dfasdfas,
    23ea3ad,
    898sd,
    xyzxyz,
    sadsdasd,
    dfasdfas,
    23ea3ad,
    898sd,
}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my answer at [How to put content from multiple databases in one table using datatool?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117747/how-to-put-content-from-multiple-databases-in-one-table-using-datatool/117763#117763), I came up with this.  Currently, this MWE reads the data from a file data.txt, currently containing

```
dfkdsfs
sdf
dsfdsfgsdfg
ds4543
rg
ere
r
ewrf
sfs
edfds
swdf
sdfdsfdsfdsf
rtg
435
rtgre
t546
tgr
ret
4trswe
dfdf
fdfsdf
435435rsggf
dsfds
gff
vcvx
gfgfd
asdfdsf
rt
34
32e3
~
```

though the external file can be dispensed with if the `\readdef{data.txt}{\tmpa}` were replaced by

```
\def\tmpa{dfkdsfs sdf dsfdsfgsdfg ds4543 rg ere r ewrf sfs edfds swdf
sdfdsfdsfdsf rtg 435 rtgre t546 tgr ret 4trswe dfdf fdfsdf 435435rsggf
dsfds gff vcvx gfgfd asdfdsf rt 34 32e3 ~
}
```

The `~` in the last row is a filler (I'll come back to that).  I'm also assuming that data entries have no spaces, which I inferred from the OP's description.  The macro `\readArrayij{\tmpa}{first}{3}` reads the data into an array identified as `first`, with 3 columns.  Partial rows are discarded, and so here is why I added a blank and newline at the end of the data, so that a partial row is not lost.

The structure uses Herbert's `\tabtoks` approach ([How to programmatically make tabular rows using `\whiledo` ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/how-to-programmatically-make-tabular-rows-using-whiledo)) to add the data to a tabular, 3 elements at a time, in this case, adding an index identifier to the front end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\newcounter{index}
\newcounter{mycell}
  % Based on:
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/
  % how-to-programmatically-make-tabular-rows-using-whiledo
  \makeatletter
  \newcounter{tabindex}
  \newtoks\@tabtoks
  \newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{%
    \@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks\stepcounter{tabindex}#1}}
  \newcommand*\resettabtoks{\@tabtoks{}}
  \newcommand*\synctabindex[1]{\setcounter{tabindex}{\value{#1}}}
  \newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
  \makeatother
\begin{document}
\readdef{data.txt}{\tmpa}
\readArrayij{\tmpa}{first}{3}

%
\resettabtoks
\setcounter{index}{0}
\setcounter{mycell}{0}
\synctabindex{index}
\whiledo{\value{index} < \numexpr\firstROWS\relax}{%

  \addtabtoks{%
    \stepcounter{mycell}
    \themycell: \arrayij{first}{\thetabindex}{1} &
    \stepcounter{mycell}
    \themycell: \arrayij{first}{\thetabindex}{2} &
    \stepcounter{mycell}
    \themycell: \arrayij{first}{\thetabindex}{3} 
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\thetabindex}{\nrows}}{\\\hline}{\\\hline}%
  }
  \addtocounter{index}{1}%
}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  \printtabtoks
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]