# merge two tables into one

Tags: tables

i have two sperate tables with the same number of rows and labels
as follows:

one:

```
a  12
b  32 
c  18
```

two:

```
a  45 
b  98
c  300
```

how can i combine those two tables into one?
as follows:

```
a 12 45
b 32 98
c 18 300
```

thank 
Elisheva

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Your question is somewhat ambiguous.  Do you mean to say that the "one:" and "two:" are in external files as text, and you would like to create a LaTeX table that looks like the third example?  If that were so, then something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117747/how-to-put-content-from-multiple-databases-in-one-table-using-datatool/117763#117763 might be useful.

Comment: i have to seperate latex's file table, i am not sure that the link you gave help me, or i am worng..?

Comment: @elishevaschwarz your question is still far from clear. What form are your two tables? As you show with space separated values? Or are they marked up as latex `tabular` already?

Comment: i have to confess that i am just a bigginer.. i add Screenshot of the two files

Comment: the first file:

Comment: ok i can't add them..., but as you said those are with space separated values

Comment: i can also make for each one of them a table which marked up as latex tabular already

Comment: Take a look at the [pgfplotstable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) package, that is able to read data from multiple files and typeset it into a table.

Answer (score 5):

The `\pgfplotstablecreatecol` command from the [`pgfplotstable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) package can be used here to add additional columns to a table when it is created:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

%the following section is just for the example; you can have your actual tables
% in separate external files
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{table1.dat}
name data1
a  12 
b  32 
c  18 
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{table2.dat}
name data2
a  45 
b  98
c  300
\end{filecontents*}
%%%% end of section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pgfplotstableread{table1.dat}{\loadedtablei}
\pgfplotstableread{table2.dat}{\loadedtableii}

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  copy column from table={\loadedtableii}{[index] 1},
  ]{data2}{\loadedtablei}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  string type,
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]{\loadedtablei}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As I mentioned in the code, the `filecontents*` section is just for the example; you can have your tables in external separate files, for example, or you can have them in your actual `.tex` file.

Here's a more real example, explaining step by step the procedure.

1. Create a file `table1.dat` like this one:

   ```
   Category Valuea
   {Share Jewish}  0.87
   {Share Muslim}  0.05
   {Share other religion}  0.08
   {Mean age}  33.28 
   {Share born in Israel}  0.69
   {Share work}  0.23
   {Share male}  0.51 
   {Share dis\_21}  0.01 
   {Share dis\_18}  0.00 
   {Share dis\_13}  0.00
   ```
2. Create a file `table2.dat` like this one:

   ```
   Category Valueb
   {Share Jewish}  0.13
   {Share Muslim}  0.51
   {Share other religion}  0.18
   {Mean age}  23.16 
   {Share born in Israel}  0.29
   {Share work}  0.15
   {Share male}  0.33 
   {Share dis\_21}  0.02 
   {Share dis\_18}  0.01 
   {Share dis\_13}  0.01
   ```

   Notice that entries with more than one word are grouped using braces. Also I provided some headings for the first row of the merged table.
3. Save these files in your current working directory (the same cotaining your `.tex` file).
4. Your `.tex` file should have the following aspect:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
   %\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

   % Read table1
   \pgfplotstableread{table1.dat}{\loadedtablei}
   % Read table2
   \pgfplotstableread{table2.dat}{\loadedtableii}

   % Create additional column for table1 containing
   % second column from table2
   \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
     copy column from table={\loadedtableii}{[index] 1},
     ]{Valueb}{\loadedtablei}

   \begin{document}

   % Print the merged table
   \pgfplotstabletypeset[
     string type,
     every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
     every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
   ]{\loadedtablei}

   \end{document}
   ```

Processing the above document yields:

[image]

Comment: @elishevaschwarz You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept the answer (if you consider it solved your problem) by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: when i do what you have told me, i got the massage: "latex error: can be used only in preamble" do you know what the meaning is, and what i have to change?

Comment: @elishevaschwarz Do you get that error with the *same exact* code I posted or with some of your own code?

Comment: i think i did the same, instead of the examle you gave me i worte "input{table1.tex}" and in the second "input{table2.rex}" after that i put it in my "big" article, again with "input{eli.tex}"

Comment: @elishevaschwarz It all depends on what exactly is on `table1.tex` and `table2.tex` (raw data as in the example in your question or already formatted tabulars?). Also notice that you don't use \input to include (and merge) your tables. You use the commands I described in my answer.

Comment: sorry for all of this...i got the massage "package pgfplots error: input 'table.dat' has an unbalanced number of cokumns in row '1' (expected '2' cols; got '1')"

Comment: @elishevaschwarz No problem. I will need to see (if possible) the actual files you are using. Can you upload elsewhere ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), for example) the files with the information for the tables and provide a link in your next comment?

Comment: so how can i include my tables without the command "input"? my table1.tex look like this: \hspace*{0.5cm}Share Jewish&        0.87\\
\hspace*{0.5cm}Share Muslim&        0.05\\
\hspace*{0.5cm}Share other religion&        0.08\\
\hspace*{0.5cm}Mean age&       33.28\\
\hspace*{0.5cm}Share born in Israel&        0.69\\
\hspace*{0.5cm}Share work&        0.23\\
\hspace*{0.5cm}Share male&        0.51\\
\hspace*{0.5cm}Share dis\_21&        0.01\\
\hspace*{0.5cm}Share dis\_18&        0.00\\
\hspace*{0.5cm}Share dis\_13&        0.00\\
and the same for table2.tex

Comment: @elishevaschwarz As you can see from my example, pgfplots takes charge of including your tables and merging them. Let me produce some code for you showing you how to proceed. Unfortunately, it's dinner time here, so I will only be able to give you the code later (one hour or so). I'll write another message when the code is ready.

Comment: @elishevaschwarz just to be sure, you want to merge the second column of table2 into table1 right?

Comment: yes, and i really dont know ihow to thank you..tell me if there any way to do that:) here (israel) is midnight so you can take your time, i will see it tomorrow morning...appetite and thank again!

Comment: @elishevaschwarz You're very kind! A "thank you" and an accepted answer (but only if my answer solves your problem) are more than enough :) I updated my answer with the code required to produce the merged table and step by step instructions on how to proceed. Please let me know if things now work as expected.

Comment: good morning! do you mean that i should chane my files by myself? i ask because i get them as they look like automatically from stata..if this is the only way it is good enough, i will try it and let you know..thank again!

Comment: @elishevaschwarz Good morning to you too! I think that you can also work with the original formatting for the tables (with the ampersands and the line changing commands (I am not totally sure about the `\hspace`s)) making some modifications to my code. I would need to do some tests. I'll let you know the results.