# import R data frame into org-mode table

Tags: emacs, r, org-mode

I have an R script that generates a data frame, that I export to a CSV file. The data looks something like this:

```
"","Variant","Xaxis","N","mean","sd","se"
"1","line1",10,5,111.11,9.33,3.11
"1","line1",20,5,112.11,9.13,3.14
"1","line1",30,5,113.11,9.43,3.10
"1","line2",10,5,101.11,8.33,2.11
"1","line2",20,5,100.11,8.13,2.12
"1","line2",30,5,108.11,8.03,2.10
```

I have an ongoing org-mode document in which I'd like to report this data. I'd like to add a table that looks something like this:

```
| Variant | X Axis | Y Axis | N | Mean | Standard Deviation | Standard Error |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The data will change frequently over the coming months. I'd like org-mode to auto-magically read a CSV file, to construct my org-table on-the-fly. I'd hoping to avoid copying and pasting results each time.

Is there some org-mode or emacs+ESS magic I can use to populate my empty table, with source data from my CSV file?

Comment: This has nothing to do with TeX, however, the org-mode mailing list is highly active and I suggest you direct your question there.

Answer (score 6):

As @zeroth pointed out, this is not a TeX question, but an orgmode question.  The solution, however, is pretty simple

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :colnames yes :exports results
  read.csv("foo.csv") 
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 5):

I put the logic right in the document, but you can encode it inside a macro, I'm pretty sure.  Note that y-axis column is blank because your R-script didn't include it.  EDITED to process comma-separated data, rather than space-separated.

Herbert's answer at [How to programmatically make tabular rows using `\whiledo` ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/how-to-programmatically-make-tabular-rows-using-whiledo) was indispensible to my solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\newcounter{index}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Rscript.txt}
"","Variant","Xaxis","N","mean","sd","se"
"1","line1",10,5,111.11,9.33,3.11
"1","line1",20,5,112.11,9.13,3.14
"1","line1",30,5,113.11,9.43,3.10
"1","line2",10,5,101.11,8.33,2.11
"1","line2",20,5,100.11,8.13,2.12
"1","line2",30,5,108.11,8.03,2.10
\end{filecontents*}
\readarraysepchar{,}
  % Based on:
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/
  % how-to-programmatically-make-tabular-rows-using-whiledo
  \makeatletter
  \newcounter{tabindex}
  \newtoks\@tabtoks
  \newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{%
    \@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks\stepcounter{tabindex}#1}}
  \newcommand*\resettabtoks{\@tabtoks{}}
  \newcommand*\synctabindex[1]{\setcounter{tabindex}{\value{#1}}}
  \newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
  \makeatother
\begin{document}
\readdef{Rscript.txt}{\tmpa}
\readArrayij{\tmpa}{first}{\ncols}
%
\resettabtoks
\setcounter{index}{0}
\synctabindex{index}
\stepcounter{index} %WILL NEED THIS TO STEP OVER HEADER LINE
\addtabtoks{ Variant & X Axis & Y Axis & N & Mean & Standard Deviation &
Standard Error \\\hline}
\whiledo{\value{index} < \nrows}{%
  \addtocounter{index}{1}%
  \addtabtoks{%
    \arrayij{first}{\thetabindex}{2} &
    \arrayij{first}{\thetabindex}{3} &
                                     &
    \arrayij{first}{\thetabindex}{4} &
    \arrayij{first}{\thetabindex}{5} &
    \arrayij{first}{\thetabindex}{6} &
    \arrayij{first}{\thetabindex}{7}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\thetabindex}{\nrows}}{}{\\}%
  }
}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \printtabtoks
  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `xtable` library of R and insert manually in the LaTeX document, or better, automatically with `Sweave` without any help of the text editor.

The following example was generated with only one file using only TeXworks, but configured to compile through R instead of using `pdflatex`:

[image: MWE]

This is the code:

```
% Test.Rnw 
% This this is not a tex file
%  run with Sweave (not with pdflatex) 
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}

<<MakingDataFrame,echo=F>>=
Variant=c('line1','line1','line1','line2','line2','line2')
Xaxis=c(10.5,20.5,30.5,10.5,20.5,30.5)
N=c(5,5,5,5,5,5)
mean=c(111.11,112.11,113.11,101.11,100.11,108.11)
sd=c(9.33,9.13,9.43,8.33,8.13,8.03)
se=c(3.11,3.14,3.10,2.11,2.12,2.10)
df = data.frame(Variant,Xaxis, mean,sd,se) 
dfraw <- df
colnames(df)<- c('Variant','X axis','Mean','Standard Deviation','Standard Error') 

@

A  \LaTeX{}  table showing a simple  {\em R} data frame: 

<<BeautifulTable,echo=F,results=tex>>=
library(xtable)
xtable(df, caption='This a xtable showing a data frame')
@

This was generated with \texttt{xtable} of  {\em R} whitin a  \LaTeX{}  (noweb) document with this raw data: 

<<ShowinDataFrame,echo=F>>=
dfraw
@

Inserting this code in a  created  true \TeX document: 

<<BeautifulTableCode,echo=F>>=
xtable(df, caption='This a xtable showing a data frame')
@

\end{document}
```

Note: I make the data frame from scratch to avoid external files in the example, but of course you can change this by importing an existing file with `read.csv` in the R chunks.