# How to fill a dynamically generated table with dynamic content?

Tags: tables, expansion, loops

how do I generate a tabular dynamically while filling it with dynamic data?

Example: Let's say I have

```
\def\N{10}
```

and I want to generate a table with `\N` columns, where the top cell of each column contains the number of the column, like

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|...|c|}
1 & 2 & 3 & ... & N
\end{tabular}
```

This was the closest I got:

```
\newtoks\cols
\cols={}
\newcounter{i}
\setcounter{i}{1}
\loop
\cols=\expandafter{\the\cols \arabic{i}}
\ifnum\value{i}<\N
\cols=\expandafter{\the\cols &}
\stepcounter{i}
\repeat

\begin{tabular}{|*{\N}{c|}}
\the\cols
\end{tabular}
```

but due to the `\expandafter`, this gives me ten columns, each containing a 10.

Is there a way to perform something like a partial expand? I'd like to expand only the `\arabic{i}` but of course not the `&`.

Comment: This question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/how-to-programmatically-make-tabular-rows-using-whiledo relates to your problem.  I have found Herbert's `\tabtoks` approach very useful.

Comment: Use `datatool` or `pgfplotstable` to avoid any column number concerns etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
\cols=\expandafter{\the\cols \arabic{i}}
```

`\cols` is a token register, thus `\arabic{i}` does not get expanded.
Using an additional `\expandafter` and printing the counter value instead of `\arabic` helps:

```
\cols=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\cols\the\value{i}}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks\cols
\newcounter{i}
\newcount\N

\begin{document}
  \N=10
  \cols={}
  \setcounter{i}{1}
  \loop
    \cols=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\cols\the\value{i}}
  \ifnum\value{i}<\N
    \cols=\expandafter{\the\cols &}
    \stepcounter{i}
  \repeat
  \begin{tabular}{|*{\N}{c|}}
    \the\cols
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Expandable version

The following example uses e-TeX's `\numexpr`. Care is taken to get a constant `\if` nesting and `&` must not be seen too early.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\N

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Ncols}{%
  \Ncols@aux{1}%
}
\newcommand*{\Ncols@aux}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1>\N
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {% 
    \ifnum#1<2 \expandafter\@gobble\fi\Ncols@amp
    #1%
    \expandafter\Ncols@aux\expandafter{\the\numexpr(#1+1)}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\Ncols@amp}{&}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\N=10
\begin{tabular}{|*{\N}{c|}}
\Ncols
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

[Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165646/4686) explained the problem with your code, how to solve it, and also how to proceed in a different style using an expandable integer loop (thanks to `\numexpr`).

[A.Ellett's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165643/4686) provides two more solutions using `pgffor` and `pgfkeys`.

[DJP' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165635/4686) is a method using an external tool, here `Python code` which is handled by the powerful `Sage` via `sagetex`.

These answers all need in one form or another some extra work, like (for the `TeX` ones) hiding the tabulation `&` in a macro, or do global definitions with `\xdef`, or prepare a token list register, or use various kinds of `TeX` conditionals.

The `xintFor` construct from package [xinttools](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) is an alternative (see [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159118/how-to-iterate-over-a-comma-separated-list/159191#159191)) which spares the trouble of this extra coding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\newcommand{\N}{10}
\begin{document}
% \renewcommand{\N}{<nb of cols>}
\begin{tabular}{*{\N}c}
  \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq {1}{\N}}\do {\xintifForFirst{}{&}#1}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: dynamic tabular]

The `\xintifForFirst{YES}{N0}` test is to insert a tabulation `&` only in the second and next cells of the given row (here only one row). The  `\xintSeq` macro generates an arithmetic sequence of integers (e.g `{1}{2}{3}{4}`). The `\xintFor* #1 in` iterates over its argument (its unstarred cousin `\xintFor` iterates over a comma separated list), letting `#1` be each item of it one after the other.

The same code as above but using rather a `LaTeX` counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\newcounter{N}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{N}{10}
\begin{tabular}{*{\value{N}}c}
  \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq {1}{\value{N}}}\do {\xintifForFirst{}{&}#1}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here is now a more elaborate example (as it uses two nested loops) which constructs multiplication tables: `\numexpr` is used for the multiplication of the row index by the column index.

> [image: dynamic tabular 2]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand\MultTable [4]{% 
  % #1, #2 row indices
  % #3, #4 column indices: we need #4-#3+2 columns
  \begin{tabular}{*{\numexpr#4-#3+2\relax}c}
  \hline
  % headerline
  $\times$\xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq {#3}{#4}}\do{&\textbf{##1}}\\
  \hline
  % #2-#1+1 rows, ##1=dynamic index of each row, ##2 column index
  \xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq {#1}{#2}}\do
     {\textbf{##1}
      \xintFor* ##2 in {\xintSeq {#3}{#4}}\do{&\the\numexpr ##1*##2\relax}
      \\
     }
  \hline
  \end{tabular}%
% efficiency note: one could do \edef\columnindices {\xintSeq {#3}{#4}}
% before the tabular
% and use \columnindices rather \xintSeq {#3}{#4} to avoid it being
% re-computed for each row
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \MultTable {1}{10}{1}{10}
  \caption{Multiplication table}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \MultTable {123}{132}{91}{98}
  \caption{Multiplication table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

As we used `\xintFor*` inside the definition of a `LaTeX` user command, we needed to double the `#` to avoid confusion between the `##1` of the loop and the `#1` being the first parameter of the command.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind learning a little Python, the `sagetex` package can handle dynamic tables easily; after all Python is a powerful language. The documentation for sagetex is [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/) and, in example.pdf, they construct Pascal's Triangle. Here's the code for something closer to what you asked for; the first row is 1 through N:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
N = 5
M = 4
output = r"\begin{tabular}{"
for i in range(0,N):
    output += r"|c"
output += r"|}"
for j in range(0,M):
    for i in range(0,N-1):
        output += r"%d & "%((j+1)*(i+1))
    output += r"%d \\"%(N*(j+1))
output += r"\end{tabular}"
\end{sagesilent}
Here's the output:\\\\
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the limited amount of Python you need to learn, I'd imagine it's probably easier than programming in TeX. You need to know: for loops don't include the last value listed in the range and r is for raw string and avoids problems that might arise from having characters such as backslash in your string. Finally, %d is for inserting integers, %f for float, and %s for string. The `sagesilent` environment is typesetting the actual code which then gets inserted via a `sagestr`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a variety of ways as already suggested by the comments and other answer.  Here are two solutions using `pgffor` and `pgfkeys`.

This first solution works without using keys:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\aeDynamicTable{\ae@dynamicTable}
\def\ae@dynamicTable[#1]#2{%%
  \let\ae@table@content\relax%%
  \def\ae@new@column{&}
  \def\ae@row{0}%%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,#2}
    {%%
      \xdef\ae@row{\number\numexpr\ae@row+1\relax}%%
      \ifx\relax\ae@table@content
        \xdef\ae@table@content{\noexpand\@arabic{\x}}%
      \else
        \xdef\ae@table@content{\expandonce{\ae@table@content} \noexpand\@arabic{\x}}%%
      \fi
      \ifnum\ae@row=#1\relax
        \xdef\ae@row{0}%%
        \def\ae@new@line{\\}%%
        \def\ae@new@column{}%%
      \else
        \def\ae@new@line{}%%
        \def\ae@new@column{&}%%
      \fi
      \ifnum\x=#2\relax
        \def\ae@new@line{}%%
        \def\ae@new@column{}%%
      \fi
      \xdef\ae@table@content{\expandonce{\ae@table@content} \expandonce{\ae@new@column} \expandonce{\ae@new@line}}%
    }%%
    \begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{c|}}
      \ae@table@content 
    \end{tabular}%%
  }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\aeDynamicTable[3]{5}

\aeDynamicTable[10]{35}

\end{document}
```

This second example accomplishes the same task using keys:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\ae@col@limit{}
\def\ae@max@cells{}
\pgfkeys{/ae/dynamic/table/.cd,
  cols/.store in=\ae@col@limit,
  cells/.store in=\ae@max@cells,
}

\newcommand\aeDynamicTable{\ae@dynamicTable}
\def\ae@dynamicTable#1{%%
  \pgfkeys{/ae/dynamic/table/.cd,#1}%% 
  \let\ae@table@content\relax%%
  \def\ae@new@column{&}
  \def\ae@col{0}%%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\ae@max@cells}
    {%%
      \xdef\ae@col{\number\numexpr\ae@col+1\relax}%%
      \ifx\relax\ae@table@content
        \xdef\ae@table@content{\noexpand\@arabic{\x}}%
      \else
        \xdef\ae@table@content{\expandonce{\ae@table@content} \noexpand\@arabic{\x}}%%
      \fi
      \ifnum\ae@col=\ae@col@limit\relax
        \xdef\ae@col{0}%%
        \def\ae@new@line{\\}%%
        \def\ae@new@column{}%%
      \else
        \def\ae@new@line{}%%
        \def\ae@new@column{&}%%
      \fi
      \ifnum\x=\ae@max@cells\relax
        \def\ae@new@line{}%%
        \def\ae@new@column{}%%
      \fi
      \xdef\ae@table@content{\expandonce{\ae@table@content} \expandonce{\ae@new@column} \expandonce{\ae@new@line}}%
    }%%
    \begin{tabular}{|*{\ae@col@limit}{c|}}
      \ae@table@content 
    \end{tabular}%%
  }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\aeDynamicTable{cols=3,cells=5}

\aeDynamicTable{cols=10,cells=35}

\end{document}
```

In either case the resulting tables are:

[image]