# Automatic amount table columns and column numbers

Tags: tables, multicolumn, automation

I'm looking for a way to create a command with which Latex can automatically generate a table with a given amount of columns, and automatically fills in the column numbers as headers.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
\newcommand{\CountBox}[1]{
    \begin{flushright}
        \begin{tabular}{*{#1}{|l}}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} #1  \\ \hline
                                #1   \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}   
    \end{flushright}
}
```

Where the following command creates the following table:

```
\CountBox{6}
```

[image: 6 Column Table]

And the following command creates the following table:

```
\CountBox{3}
```

[image: 3 Column Table]

I seem to get stuck on having to manually input the ampersands into the multicolumn command (have tried \loop, \while, and \expandafter)

Thanks for the help!

---

Just in case the original code for the 6 column table:

```
\begin{flushright}
    \begin{tabular}{*{7}{|l}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline 
                            &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}   
\end{flushright}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165625/how-to-fill-a-dynamically-generated-table-with-dynamic-content might be helpful

Comment: any reason for centering the `1` in its cell and not the others ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\foreach` in TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}       
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{
    positioning,
    shapes.multipart
    }
\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        text centered,
    },
}
\newcommand{\CountBox}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[mynode] (1) {1};
        \ifnumcomp{#1}{=}{1}{}{%
            \foreach \mynum 
                [evaluate=\mynum as \myprev using int(\mynum-1)]  
                in {2,...,#1}
            \node[mynode,xshift=-\pgflinewidth,anchor=west] (\mynum) at (\myprev.east) {\mynum};
            }%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\begin{document}
\CountBox{1} 

\CountBox{3}

\CountBox{6}

\CountBox{2} 
\CountBox{4}
\CountBox{7} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response! Works like a charm.

Comment: @Phlemp You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 5):

Here is an `expl3` implementation. With the help of `array` and its `w` column specifier, all columns can be made as wide as the last (with the largest number).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,array}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\CountBox}{m}
 {
  % measure the wider number
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
  % do as many columns as specified
  \begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{w{c}{\l_tmpa_dim}|}}
  \hline
  % do '<number> &' one less than specified, then add the last number
  \int_step_function:nN { #1 - 1 } \__phlemp_countbox_head:n #1 \\
  \hline
  % generate as many &'s as necessary to fill the second row
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 - 1 } { & } \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }

% auxiliary function for adding the & after the number
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__phlemp_countbox_head:n { #1 & }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\CountBox{3} \CountBox{10}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It produced a lot of illegal pream-tokens on my side though (working in Overleaf). Also did not allow the _ outside of math-mode, and an undefined control sequence on " \int_step_function:nN ". Is that something I can fix or have to install something for? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The following uses [`multido`](//ctan.org/pkg/multido) to generate the column numbering sequence and blank row. A similar approach to egreg's uses [`array`](//ctan.org/pkg/array)'s `w{<align>}{<width>}` to set the column width to the widest element:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido,array}

\newcounter{boxCount}
\newlength{\boxCountwd}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\CountBox}[1]{%
  \setcounter{boxCount}{0}% Reset boxCount
  \settowidth{\boxCountwd}{#1}% Measure widest element
  \def\CountBoxSeq{\@gobble}%
  \def\CountBoxSeqPhantom{\@gobble}%
  \multido{\i=1+1}{#1}{%
    \xdef\CountBoxSeq{\CountBoxSeq & \i}%
    \xdef\CountBoxSeqPhantom{\CountBoxSeqPhantom &}%
  }%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{ *{#1}{|w{c}{\boxCountwd}} | }
    \hline
    \CountBoxSeq \\
    \hline
    \CountBoxSeqPhantom \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\CountBox{5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I try compiling it produces illegal pream tokens on the "w" and on the "\boxCountwd" in the tabular. I don't know how to fix it. Working in Overleaf. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Phlemp: Did you add `\usepackage{array}` to your preamble like I did? Probably not. You don't have to use `w{c}{..}` as a column specification. It just aids in making the column widths the same if you have 10 or more columns. Alternatively, just use `c`, `l` or `r`.