# Repetition inside tabular

Tags: tabularx, for-loop

Are there any simple way to perform repetition inside a tabular environment?

This is what I intended to do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}


\newcommand\encircle[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] 
    \node (X) [draw, shape=circle, inner sep=0] {\strut #1};}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \newcounter{qno}
  \setcounter{qno}{1}
  \whiledo{\value{qno} < 41}{
  \theqno.
  & \encircle{a}
  & \encircle{b}
  & \encircle{c}
  & \encircle{d}
  & \encircle{e}
  \\
  \hline
  \stepcounter{qno}  
  }
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

But it produces an compilation error, a blank page, and a table with three extra lines at the end.

I am aware of [a possible solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/how-to-programmatically-make-tabular-rows-using-whiledo), but I was wondering if there is any solution that do no require redefining things.

Comment: Any solution will use a strategy similar to the one used in the post that you quoted. This is due to the special way used by ``tabular``(x)(*) to handle his content. It should be fully available at the whole when TeX start to parsing it, which not the case if the loop is inside the tabular.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy with `expl3`, because `\int_step_function:nnnN` delivers its result before TeX restarts to examine the output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\encircle[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
  \node (X) [draw, shape=circle, inner sep=0] {\strut #1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\maketabularlines}{mm}
 {
  \int_step_function:nnnN { 1 } { 1 } { #1 } #2
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand{\abcdeline}{m}{%
  #1. 
  & \encircle{a}
  & \encircle{b}
  & \encircle{c}
  & \encircle{d}
  & \encircle{e}
  \\
  \hline
 }

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\maketabularlines{10}{\abcdeline}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You can use different macros in place of `\abcdeline` so long as the argument to the macro is the current index in the loop.

[image]